# Body's response to rapid ingestion of water?

Tags: renal

As we are all aware, if you drink a large quantity of water in a short time period, you will  likely have to go to the toilet not too long afterwards.

The body detects the increase in fluid volume (or more precisely in this instance the decrease in sodium concentration) and kicks off the renin-angiotensin-aldosterone pathway.

This ultimately results in a decrease in anti-diuretic hormone (ADH) which in turn decreases water absorption from the collecting ducts and distal convoluted tubule in the kidney.

So my question is, if we rapidly consume a large volume of water in a very short period of time, could the resulting decrease in ADH hormone overshoot the mark and result in the body eliminating more water than what is ideal.

That is, could drinking a large amount of water in a short time actually have a dehydrating effect?

Comment: `the resulting increase in ADH` - decrease?

Comment: @Susan, yes susan thanks.  I had it correct in paragraph 3 but not in paragraph 4.  I have edited.

Comment: Considering that drinking large amounts of water in a short period of time has resulted in numerous fatalities due to water intoxication, it's an unlikely subject for research.

Comment: @CareyGregory, perhaps we could study this in animals.

Comment: Toward what end? It's not obvious what practical use this information would have, so obtaining grants and getting the study past an ethics committee would be problematic.

Comment: @CareyGregory, like you said many die from drinking too much water so the more info we have about it the better.

Comment: @CareyGregory, furthermore, often in science the usefulness of a discovery isn't known until many years after it is made.  Take tensors in maths for example.  Who would have thought such trivial objects would soon become the way we describe the shape of our universe and have applications in modern GPS.

Comment: Understood, but this isn't basic science -- it's clinical research and you're going to be harming, perhaps killing, lab animals. That's a higher standard to meet for research funding and ethics committee approval. I think you would need some supporting science since the hypothesis flies in the face of what we know about the renal system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't belive it is possible for the body to produce too much ADH.  The body will likely produce insufficient ADH to eliminate the ingested water, thus you will still remain in a state of hyponatremia even after the body's ADH response.

The body will then return to homeostatus by reducing thirst.

This means of course that if you ingest too much water (ignoring your lack of thirst) you can create serious health problems for yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Health SE! This post has the makings of a very good answer, but here on Health, we [*strongly encourage*](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/1) using references. They are the only way in which we can tell if information is reliable or not. If you are struggling to find good sources, check out, [What are reliable sources?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/112) If you want to learn more about our site's stance on answers without references, check out, [Should answers without references be immediately deleted?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/q/283) Thanks :)